# How to iterate over nested array and add elements in sub array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add participant in one of the `subarray` depending on the `groupId`. How to iterate over `subarray` and compare the `groupId` in javascript.
I am using angular js and console.log($scope.groupDetails4GroupAdded) returns this object in chome inspect.

```
0: Object
$$hashKey: "object:30"
domain: "IND"
groupID: 109
groupName: "Disha"
owner: "JACK"
participants: Array[3]
__proto__: Object
1: Object
$$hashKey: "object:31"
domain: "IND"
groupID: 120
groupName: "home"
owner: "tOM"
participants: Array[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter by `groupId`you should use `filter` :

```
const matchedItems = array.filter(item => item.groupId === 109);
```

To retrieve all participants that satisfy this condition you can then call reduce on the result :

```
const participants = array
  .filter(item => item.groupId === 109)
  .reduce((result, item) => [...result, ...item.participants], []);
```

If you only need one match :

```
const matchedItem = array.find(item => item.groupId === 109);
```

See [MDN array documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array) for more array relative methods.

Comment: @MattieuLemoine var desiredObject=$scope.groupDetails4GroupAdded.filter(function (el) {
         return el.groupID===$scope.groupId
       });
   In the variable desiredObject my Object with matching groupID is coming. But desiredObject.participants is undefined.   desiredObject.participants.push(friendDetails);//showing error as push on undefined

Comment: desiredObject is not an object it's an array of item that satisfy ``item.groupId === 109``. ``filter``returns an array.

Comment: should I apply loop on var desiredObject to reach participants?

Comment: Can you be more specific ? It may be related to the array spread operator. You can use ``concat``instead

Answer (score 0):

as you haven't provide any further information, I'll just answer the question I've identified. How to iterate over subarray

```
for (var i = 0; i< Object.participants.length; i++){
Object.participants[i] //participant object.
}
```

if you want to add a participant in this subarray

```
Object.participants.push(objectParticipant) //objectParticipant is an object defined by you
```

Comment: you will get this if your array is empty...just check if your array is empty before to iterate over it.

Comment: No my array is not empty. It is having above 2 elements. But name of this array is groupDetails4GroupAdded . It should be like groupDetails4GroupAdded.Object.participants.push(objectParticipant)?

Comment: probably, yes! because of this you need to provide more information about your code. Without it is really hard to help. It seems that this `Object` is from you console not the name of your object...so you probably need to iterate over `groupDetails4GroupAdded.participants` and add to it `groupDetails4GroupAdded.participants.push(objectParti‌​cipant)` without `Object`

Comment: You need to provide your code...it won't work guessing what you're trying to achieve.